# Converting from IEEE-754 to decimal

Tags: ieee-754

I want to convert the number 0xAEF00000 from IEEE-754(1985) to a decimal value. Until know I did it as follows,
I converted it to 32 bit pattern.

Now I am stuck how to convert it further. Please help me out.

Comment: this sounds suspiciously like homework.

Comment: Based on the OP’s comment below (“I am using that website for the proof of the results but I need to do it manually”) this is _definitely_ homework.  Retagging.

Answer (score 1):

Given how the question is posed, it seems that you need to do this as a one off. If that's the case, I would simply use the online IEEE-754 calculator: [link](http://babbage.cs.qc.edu/IEEE-754/32bit.html).

It not only converts the number to the decimal floating-point representation, it also shows all the relevant bit patterns.

In the question you don't state the endianness of your 32-bit int, so you might need to swap the byte order before entering the number into the calculator.

Comment: I am using that website for the proof of the results but I need to do it manually.

Answer (score 1):

Take a close look at the result of the calculator aix pointed to in his answer:

```
Binary32: AEF00000
Status      Sign [1]      Exponent [8]      Significand [23]
Normal      1 (-)         01011101 (-34)    1.11100000000000000000000 (1.875)
```

Write out the full binary pattern for `0xAEF00000`: `10101110111100000000000000000000`.

Split this according to the pattern the calculator shows: `1 01011101 11100000000000000000000`.

You now have the sign bit, the biased exponent value, and the significand without the implicit leading bit.  This should be enough to make a start on interpreting the value.